# How do you prevent snapcraft stage including the absolute path with the python3 plugin?

Tags: python3, snap

... or what am i doing wrong?

Hi, i'm snapping a project which has two parts, one using the make plugin and one using the python3 plugin.

However, after staging the python3 part, if i look in the stage directory, it contains my python files at the end of a very long (the absolute) path.

```
{staging dir}/home/username/Documents/silky/parts/server/install/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/*my python files here*
```

where as i would expect them to be:

```
{staging dir}/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/*my python files here*
```

i don't have this issue with the part using the make plugin.

my setup.py is pretty simple:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="server",
    packages=['server']
    )
```

is this an issue with the python3 plugin, or am i doing something wrong?

with thanks

Comment: This is just a bug and fixed in snapcraft 2.17

Comment: snapcraft 2.17 btw has a much improved python plugin set

Comment: is there a PPA for 2.17 somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

> This is just a bug and fixed in snapcraft 2.17

thanks @sergiusens

available from this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/snapcraft-daily
```

Comment: Please don't keep this ppa enabled after installing as it will probably break in the future